# Where did I make a mistake in my SQL statement?

Tags: c#, sql

I want to get data from database by filtering 4 columns. First column name is `Money` (amount of money) and the second is `Currency`. There are two additional columns in the db with the same definitions for example: `Money2` and `Currency2`.

So I want to get all records where `Money` is larger than 100 and `Currency` is USD, but additionally I want to get all data where `Money2` is larger than 200 and `Currency2` is EUR.

I have the following query, but unfortunately it doesn't give results from the second query.

Code:

```
SELECT * 
FROM DB 
WHERE (Money > 100 AND Currency = 'USD' OR Money2 > 200 AND Currency2 = 'EUR')
```

Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: What is your table name, Is it DB?

Comment: So a little experimenting shows that operator precedence is likely not the issue here, as myself and many other posters thought- play with the following query to see this:

select 'doesnt matter' where (1=1 and 1=1 or 1=0 and 1=0)

We likely need more information from the op about the database / table structure and information on the underlying data to see the problem more clearly.

Comment: Have you tried split two ORed conditions into a UNION statement? (I've query with UNION operator but while posting that comment SO gives an error message; sorry)

Comment: with UNION this query is working, thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried a `UNION`? This will allow you to run each query independently and help you narrow down the issue.

```
select * from db where Money > 100 and currency = 'USD'
UN ION
select * from db where Money2 > 200 AND Currency2 = 'EUR'
```

(Note that space in `UNION` is intentional; without it SO doesn't want to post this answer)

Answer (score 5):

You may be running into an operator precedence issue.

Try forcing the evaluation order using parentheses. Also use .0 to avoid possible unintended conversions to int.

```
SELECT * FROM DB 
WHERE ((Money > 100.0 AND Currency = 'USD') OR (Money2 > 200.0 AND Currency2 = 'EUR'))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM DB 
WHERE (Money > 100 AND Currency = 'USD') OR (Money2 > 200 AND Currency2 = 'EUR')
```

Answer (score 1):

After FROM needs to be a name of a table, DB doesn't sound like a name of a table

```
USE DB
SELECT * 
FROM --TABLE NAME-- 
WHERE (Money > 100 AND Currency = 'USD') OR (Money2 > 200 AND Currency2 = 'EUR')
```